How can I, from a Numba jitted function, call another Numba jitted function with a pointer?
I have several Numba jitted functions f_i with the same signature.
I want to dynamically call them from another jitted function g.
I would like to :

store the pointers to the functions f_i in an Numpy array a
from g:

given an index i, retrieve from a the pointer to function f_i
dereference the pointer and call function f_i



How can I do this?
I have some code that runs, but only when JIT compilation is disabled.

In Numba, I do not think you can wrap a function pointer like you could in C. And even in C, it would not be type-safe because you have wrap this in a void*. At least, you cannot with the high-level API. In the low-level one, it is certainly possible, however, it may neither be portable, nor save. Wrapping a function pointer to a JIT function is dangerous because the pointer is not referenced so the function can be freed resulting in a dangling reference/pointer. You can play with function pointer but they need to be typed (and Numba have some additional constraints on them).

It seems that you don't need to handle "pointers" for what you want to do. How about this approach instead?

is it practical to just call the functions outright?
